# How To Set The ScrollBar in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I Want To Set The ScrollBar To Windows Phone 7.Hare There Is No Built in Control Of Scrollbar.How To Get It And Use in Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the UI design for the phone is that screen real estate is not wasted by constantly displaying unnecessary controls, such as a scrollbar.

For the most part, a scroll bar is displayed automatically while you the user is scrolling. The scrollbar then disappears once scrolling is complete.

Take a look at the default template for a List application. It creates a Listbox containing more items tha can be displayed on screen at once. While these items are scrolled the scrollbar is shown.

Answer (score 1):

you can use also more generic control ScrollViewer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v=vs.95).aspx